# Logic for tracking hours worked

Tags: time, clock

I was wanting to write a program in C that I can simply type in the hours that I worked for each day of the week, including time on break, that will take my input and return the total number of hours I have worked for that week.  It's dumb, I know, but I am not sure how to do the math for this regarding time on the clock.

Thank you

Comment: What "math regarding time on the clock" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

At beginning of work: get the current date, make it into seconds.

At end of work: get the current date, make it into seconds.

So working seconds = end seconds - beginning seconds

Then you'll just have to make those into hours.